# I keep getting error codes while trying to edit a database in PyCharm

Tags: mysql, pycharm

I try:

```
    cursor = client.cursor()

    query = "INSERT INTO t_table (column_1,column_2) VALUES (%s)"
    values = ['temp', 'temp']

    cursor.execute(query, values)

    client.commit()

    print(cursor.rowcount, "record inserted")

finally:
    client.close()
```

The error

> "MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted
> during bytes formatting"

keeps appearing. I have gone through the syntax error and GEOMETRY field error but I'm stuck at this one.

Answer (score 0):

For two values you need also to placeholders

```
try:

    cursor = client.cursor()

    query = "INSERT INTO t_table (column_1,column_2) VALUES (%s,%s)"
    values = ['temp', 'temp']

    cursor.execute(query, values)

    client.commit()

    print(cursor.rowcount, "record inserted")

finally:
    client.close()
```